# How to create a NuGet package using .csproj and external references?

Tags: svn, jenkins, nuget

My purpose is not only to build a .Net code using Nuget repositories but to implement a CI process where we will be downloading the Nuget packages from Nexus Nuget Group repository. SVN as a software versioning and revision control system and Jenkins as a CI tool.
Now my purpose is to download nuget packages using Nexus repository, downloading the code using SVN and build the code using Jenkins using MSbuild.
Here as per my understanding, you are asking me to download the packages from Visual Studio and then upload the entire code including binaries into SVN which is not something that I want.
Also, I want to upload the output of the build back into Nexus so that it can be taken by child reference, if any.
Under this scenario how can I use nuget repository with Visual Studio?
Can you propose any steps for the same.

Answer (score 0):

> How to create a NuGet package using .csproj and external references?

Try the solution I published here: [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/804005/Automated-Creation-of-NuGet-Packages), [Visual Studio extension](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f61321d6-64ac-4aad-876b-4e0a45b04f40), [project site](https://pubcomp.codeplex.com/).

It will enable you to create NuGet packages from one or more projects including definition of dependencies on other NuGets (both external to solution and created within same build).

Comment: @OndrejSotolar I fixed the link and added two more.